# Adding custom code to SWIG wrapper

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am using SWIG to interface between C++ and Python. I want to add some code to the generated wrapper for setting a member variable in a struct. The closest I have found is this:

```
%allowexception TAxis::Min;
%exception TAxis::Min
%{
  $action
  do_something();
%}

struct TAxis
{
  double Min;
  double Max;
};
```

However, this will call do_something() when TAxis::Min is both read and written. I want it to be called only when TAxis::Min is written. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. The following creates a macro VAR_WITH_SET_CODE, which can be used to do something before and after the variable is set.

```
%define VAR_WITH_SET_CODE(class, type, member, pre_code, post_code)
%extend class
{
  type member; 
}

%{
  #define class ## _ ## member ## _get(self) self->member
  #define class ## _ ## member ## _set(self, value) {pre_code} self->member = value; {post_code}  
%}
%enddef

VAR_WITH_SET_CODE(TAxis, double, Min, do_before();, do_after();)
VAR_WITH_SET_CODE(TAxis, double, Max, do_before();, do_after();)
struct TAxis
{
//double Min;
//double Max;
};
```